# Research on technology enhanced learning?

Tags: teaching, technology

The discourse about teaching seems to be dominated recently by the idea of technology enhanced learning. I have been talking a lot with colleagues about that and there seems to be some kind of consensus that the usage of technology is most of the times beneficial.

It also seems that many take this route in order to make their lectures interesting and load the with interesting "stuff" (animations, videos, etc).

I am very sceptical about this and I am kind of worried that making lectures "too interesting" can be a problem. I tend to think that students need to pace themselves and if you drag them along your lecture they end up remembering nothing.

Is there any serious research done on this? Do we understand the effects that fast-paced interesting lectures have on learning? Is there any research-based list of good and bad practices?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, of course there is serious research on this and I invite you to search it out. But I will speak only from my long (45 years) of experience.

Flash will catch their interest and might make them cheer, but it won't teach them much of anything. What the instructor does in the classroom is far less important than what the student does on her/his own and in collaboration with other students.

It is practice and feedback that teaches you. There is an interesting book, [The Art of Changing the Brain](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1579220541) that explains why this is. In order to learn, it is necessary to actually re-wire the brain: changing the synaptic connections between neurons - physical changes. That doesn't happen instantaneously (practice) and learning can go wrong if we reinforce the wrong things (feedback).

I've had the following experience and so have many others. I give a lecture and walk out feeling terrible. I made a mistake. I stumbled over something that should have been simple. I struggled to find my way back to a better place and finally ended with something sensible. A failed lecture.

But then the students I meet in the hallway tell me what a *great* lecture it was. In fact, I showed them the struggle we must go through to come to something like the truth.

I've also had the opposite experience. In teaching statistics I wanted students to have a clear idea about sampling and how means of samples relate to the overall mean of the population. I created the *absolutely perfect* lecture. It was logically flawless and exceedingly interesting. It used a special trick so that students weren't likely to confuse the two uses of the word "mean" in sampling. I was damn brilliant.

But, of course, the universal response from the students was "Huh?".

Be aware that as a teacher, your students are unlike you. The exception would be if you are teaching doctoral students. They are likely to be a lot like you, but the others are not. Everyone learns differently, but few - vanishingly few - learn from seeing something once, no matter how brilliant.

The different "learning modalities" are quite distinct and not shared by many. You need different ways to approach the material you are teaching so that different people can relate to it. Some will do with reading, others seeing, others hearing, etc.

But all need reinforcement and feedback. Students need practice and reflection on that practice.

My mantra as a teacher was "It doesn't matter what I, the teacher, do. It only matters what *you*, the student, do." Maybe not absolutely accurate, of course, but a good philosophy for students to have.

If they don't work as hard at learning as a skilled athlete does at their sport, they aren't going to excel.

Comment: I wish I could give plus 10....

Comment: _It was logically flawless and exceedingly interesting_ — I knew _exactly_ where this was going.

Comment: @JeffE, sadly, I didn't. But it was a good lesson for me in the long run.